# jQuery won't href

Tags: jquery, function, click, center

I try to move my `nav` up to the wrappers top, load the `href`'ed side and load the content after that. Currently, it's just moving up and load the content of the index.html but it won't load the given link. Why?

HTML:

```
    <nav id="main_navigation">
        <ul>
            <li id="nav_1"><a href="portfolio.htm">portfolio</a></li>
            <li id="nav_2"><a href="about.htm"></a></li>
            <li id="nav_3"><a href="blog.htm"></a></li>
            <li id="nav_4"><a href="contact.htm"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section id="content"></section>

    <section id="footer">
        <section id="back"></section>
    </section>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery.fn.center = function (centerCallback) { 

    this.css("position","absolute"); 
    this.css("top", ( $(window).height() - this.height() ) / 2+$(window).scrollTop() + "px"); 
    this.css("left", ( $(window).width() - this.width() ) / 2+$(window).scrollLeft() + "px"); 

    if(centerCallback != undefined){    
        centerCallback(this);   
        return this;    
    } 
}

var navi_switch = true; 
var content_container = 'test'; 

$(document).ready(function(){    

    $('#wrapper').center(function(){ 

        $('#main_navigation').css("top", ( >parseInt($('#main_navigation').parent().height()) - >parseInt($('#main_navigation').height()) ) / 2 + "px");    
        });

        $('#main_navigation a').click(function(){

            var attr = $(this).attr('href');    

            if(navi_switch){

                $('#main_navigation').animate({
                    top: '0', duration: 'slow'},500,function(){
                        navi_switch = false;
                        $('#content').load(attr);        
                    });     
            }
            else{
                $('#content').load(attr);           
            }
        }
}
```

Does anyone know where I'm wrong or what's wrong?

Comment: "href" is an anchor attribute, not a verb. What do you mean by _"won't href?"_ One big fix: code formatting and indentation.

Comment: It wont link my link which is given in the href attribute.

Comment: Thanks. Currently I got sometimes problems by formating the code here in stackoverflow. Thanks a lot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

attr is out of scope in the animate function. Move it to the same scope as navi_switch or you can try [this approach](http://fisherwebdev.com/wordpress/2009/06/08/scope-issues-with-the-callback-to-jquerys-animate-function/).

Comment: I tried this:
`var navi_switch = true;
var content_container = 'test';
var attr = $(this).attr('href');
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#wrapper').center(function(){ 
 $('#main_navigation').css("top", ( parseInt($('#main_navigation').parent().height()) - parseInt($('#main_navigation').height()) ) / 2 + "px");
    });  
    
    $('#main_navigation a').click(function(){
 if(navi_switch){
     $('#main_navigation').animate({
      top: '0',
   duration: 'slow'
  },500,function(){
     navi_switch = fa [...more code]`

Answer (score 0):

The key here is http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/ which stops the default action of your links from happening (that is, get the page in the href-attribute).

You can pass in the event to the click-callback, thus making event.preventDefault() possible to call. I cleaned up your code a little bit, enclosed the code in an IIFE (http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), and also added the small snippet needed for this to work. Your code was lacking some closing of `click()` and `$(document).ready()` too, so I added that as well.

```
(function($) {
    jQuery.fn.center = function(centerCallback) {
        this.css("position", "absolute");
        this.css("top", ($(window).height() - this.height()) / 2 + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
        this.css("left", ($(window).width() - this.width()) / 2 + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
        if (centerCallback != undefined) {
            centerCallback(this);
            return this;
        }
    }

    var navi_switch = true;
    var content_container = 'test';
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#wrapper').center(function() {
            $('#main_navigation').css("top", ( > parseInt($('#main_navigation').parent().height()) - > parseInt($('#main_navigation').height())) / 2 + "px");
        });
        $('#main_navigation a').click(function(e) {
            var attr = $(this).attr('href');
            if (navi_switch) {
                $('#main_navigation').animate({
                    top: '0',
                    duration: 'slow'
                }, 500, function() {
                    navi_switch = false;
                    $('#content').load(attr);
                });
            } else {
                $('#content').load(attr);
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The IIFE/iffy-part is the whole `(function($) {})(jQuery);` thing wrapping your code. In short, this ensures that $ actually is jQuery in your script, just in case you load another script. It also helps keep functions and variables out of the global window namespace, which is a good thing ;)

Comment: Now it load the side, but currently with this code it wont animate BEFORE the href.
Is there a possibility with jQuery to move the nav up, HOLD IT there every side and load the content of the linked side?
I read something about loading #content of other sides while showing http://www.url.xx/otherside.html in the bar

Thanks a lot for sharing this Jesper!

Comment: Well, withtout seeing more of your solution it's hard to say exactly what you mean. Could you make a jsfiddle or something just to illustrate what you mean, because I'm not following.